# Misterious slow performance on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, ssd, performance

asus zenbook ux32vd

Windows 10, Windows 8.1 , At first, they both work fine, but after several months of using I experience terrible lags when I: 
Play youtube
Edit photos
Edit videos
visit website full of javascript

The lags: cursor is slowed down. If I listen music stored locally, the sound is like robot, overally very slowed down computer.

I've reinstaled different OS several times to be confided to say that it's only with Win10 and Win8.1.
Apart from these tasks, PC boot fast, explored, desktop all work smooth.

I'm running now Win7 for more than year and everything is supersmooth. I can edit heavy videos, raw photos, atd ...

Linux Ubuntu also works perfect.

I've replaced SSD as I believed that there can be problem. It was not.

Guys, being software developer and sitting behind PC 15years every day, I have not idea what can cause that behavious.

Please help, Win7 is old to use.

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking at the CPU load and where it is going?  How about memory use?  A quick check can be done by going to the task manager-> details tab.  Add column for CPU time and sort by that.  DWM.exe, WUDFHost.exe, and MSMpEng.exe are surely up at the top, but what else?  Also, try (temporarily) disabling defend and startup items from the startup tab.

Comment: I do not not have Win10 installed now so I can't check it. My question is actually, what makes Win7 different from Win10...both supposed to be lightweight. 
It's 100% not the fault of the hardware.

Comment: The memory and CPU usage are not on the top. It has lags (sound and visual) even when there is a lot of physical ram and CPU power left.